# Combining Column charts and line charts with the same same data in the same container(Highcharts)

Tags: angularjs, json, highcharts, spline

I want to build a combination chart with a column chart with multiple series and a line chart. Problem is that I am getting High charts data from nested JSON response. For that I initialized array and that array is giving in series in plotoptions highcharts as you can see in the below code.

My code is like this:

```
var crime_data=[];
                   for(var i=0;i<result.themes.length;i++){
                          var crime={};
                          var test2 = result.themes[i];
                          var test = test2[Object.keys(test2)];
                         crime.name = Object.keys(result.themes[i]);
                         crime.data = [];
                           for(var k=0;k<test.yearTheme.length;k++){
                               var test3=test.yearTheme[k];
                              var test5=test3.individualValueVariable;
                               for(var j=0;j<test5.length;j++){
                                crime.data.push(test5[j].count);
                          };
                        };
                         crime_data.push(crime);
                             };

    var crimeChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
     renderTo: 'container1',
     type:'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Crime'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: month,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        }
    },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
    }, 
    tooltip: {

        shared: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {

        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,

            depth: 25,
             allowPointSelect: true,
             cursor: 'pointer',
             point: {

              },

        }
    },
 series: crime_data

});
```

This is Column chart I am getting when i write chart type column.
[image]

This is my Line Chart I am getting when i changed type column to spline in chart in highcharts.

[image]

And this is my JSON data(Highcharts data):

```
{
  "boundaries": {
    "boundary": [
      {
        "boundaryId": "55083021003",
        "boundaryType": "USA_CITY",
        "boundaryRef": "C1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "themes": [
    {
      "AssaultCrimeTheme": {
        "boundaryRef": "C1",
        "individualValueVariable": [
          {
            "name": "2013 Assault Crime",
            "description": "Assault Crime for 2013",
            "count": 18901
          },
          {
            "name": "2014 Assault Crime",
            "description": "Assault Crime for 2014",
            "count": 17707
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "BurglaryCrimeTheme": {
        "boundaryRef": "C1",
        "individualValueVariable": [
          {
            "name": "2013 Burglary Crime",
            "description": "Burglary Crime for 2013",
            "count": 17743
          },
          {
            "name": "2014 Burglary Crime",
            "description": "Burglary Crime for 2014",
            "count": 14242
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to combine both of them in the same container with same data.The problem is in how to tell highcharts multiple series should be represented with line and  with column type with same data.For this when i write series:[{ data: crime_data ,type: spline }] instead of series:crime_data In that case I am not getting Highcharts data. Can anyone Please help me how should i do this.Please suggest me.

Comment: add type in each array value, for details refer this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data, like below format. add type of chart in each data series;
Here i replaced type value but with same data.

```
 [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'AssaultCrimeTheme',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'BurglaryCrimeTheme',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'AssaultCrimeTheme',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'BurglaryCrimeTheme',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    },]
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/) for more details.

Comment: This is the problem how should i pass data in this format because  my JSON is nested JSON . Please suggest me. And I want both column chart and line chart(trend line).

Comment: You mentioned like, created array with series data from nested JSON. So you can use that array, then push same object two more times with different type value. Can you post your **crime_data** array value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example using your data.

```
const json = {
  "boundaries": {
    "boundary": [{
      "boundaryId": "55083021003",
      "boundaryType": "USA_CITY",
      "boundaryRef": "C1"
    }]
  },
  "themes": [{
    "AssaultCrimeTheme": {
      "boundaryRef": "C1",
      "individualValueVariable": [{
        "name": "2013 Assault Crime",
        "description": "Assault Crime for 2013",
        "count": 18901
      }, {
        "name": "2014 Assault Crime",
        "description": "Assault Crime for 2014",
        "count": 17707
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "BurglaryCrimeTheme": {
      "boundaryRef": "C1",
      "individualValueVariable": [{
        "name": "2013 Burglary Crime",
        "description": "Burglary Crime for 2013",
        "count": 17743
      }, {
        "name": "2014 Burglary Crime",
        "description": "Burglary Crime for 2014",
        "count": 14242
      }]
    }
  }]
}

// Create categories object in order filter duplicates
const cats = {}
const series = json.themes.map((o) => {
  const key = Object.keys(o)[0]
  return {
    name: key,
    data: o[key].individualValueVariable.map((o) => {
      cats[o.name] = 1
      return { category: o.name, y: o.count }
    })
  }
})

// Convert categories object to array
const categories = Object.keys(cats)

// Chart options
const options = {
  chart: {type: 'column'},
  xAxis: {categories: categories},
  series: series
}

// Create chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)

console.log(series, categories)
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo323gq3/

Output below:

[image]